# Creating a view with comparision in IF ELSE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, mysql-workbench

So I have decided to a create a view from my existing table but I am not able to use the Comparison condition for them. The question is if my budget is less than the price then it should display as 1 in the column or else 0. Also, the column should be a boolean called RiskyorNot.For that there is a formula that I used but couldn't get it down because of some mysql syntax error. Any help Below is my statement:

```
CREATE VIEW PricevsAllowance as SELECT c.names AS 'category name ',a.maxamt AS 'allowance', tot.totalexpend  AS 'total expenditure',RiskyorNot BOOLEAN FROM Category c JOIN allowance a ON c.allow_id = a.allow_id JOIN Totalexpanddetail t ON t.cat_num = c.cat_num
           IF(a.maxPercentage *(a.maximumprice/100)) THEN
                RiskyorNot = '1'
           ELSE 
                RiskyorNot = '0'
           END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

A view cannot contain procedural logic, which is exactly what an IF ELSE construct is. You will only be able to use logical expressions in your view. Try using the [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)  here. This will allow to you write an expression which can be evaluated when the view is queried.

```
CASE 
    WHEN a.maxPercentage * (a.maximumprice / 100)
    THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS RiskyOrNot
```

You will also need to place this CASE statement into the column list you started above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted the [`if()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, not the [`IF` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html). The latter cannot be used in a query. Also the `if()` has to go in the column list. And aliases with spaces (especially a the end) tend to cause headaches in the future.

```
CREATE VIEW pricevsallowance
AS
SELECT c.names category_name,
       a.maxamt allowance,
       tot.totalexpend total_expenditure,
       if(a.maxpercentage * a.maximumprice / 100, 1, 0) riskyornot
       FROM category c
            INNER JOIN allowance a
                       ON c.allow_id = a.allow_id
            INNER JOIN totalexpanddetail t
                       ON t.cat_num = c.cat_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix your syntax error:

```
CREATE VIEW PricevsAllowance as
    SELECT c.names AS category_name,
           a.maxamt AS allowance,
           tot.totalexpend AS total_expenditure,
           a.maxPercentage * (a.maximumprice / 100)  as RiskyorNot
    FROM Category c JOIN
         allowance a
         ON c.allow_id = a.allow_id JOIN
         Totalexpanddetail t
         ON t.cat_num = c.cat_num;
```

This may or may not calculate `RiskyOrNot` correctly.  Without sample data, desired results, and a better explanation of the logic, others can only guess at what the logic really should be.

Notes:

- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Use backticks to escape identifiers.
- I changed the names of the columns, so they do not need to be escaped.
- A string constant is not a boolean.  The expression itself simply works.

Comment: Wouldn't `a.maxPercentage * (a.maximumprice / 100)` not necessarily be equal to 1 if not equal 0 but more or less any number not equal 0 (depending on the variable values)? Unless there is some reason why this expression can only yield 0 or 1 I'm not seeing. I guess the OP wanted 0 for the expression being equal to 0 but 1 for **any other** result.

Comment: @stickybit . . . I clarified the answer.  I interpreted the question as being about the syntax error rather than the logic for the column, because the question doesn't have enough information to address the logic.